# Error:500 in MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, error-handling

I am getting Error:500, when I hit the url (copy paste the url and press enter) but it is not reproducible all the time.

Even after getting the error, if I refresh the page it will work fine.

Don't know exactly what is causing this issue. How to dig into this?

Please suggest me how to handle such scenario.

Comment: Under debug 500s would usually be an exception or error being thrown. Is this in production?

Comment: It's in local. I missed to take the screenshot of this.

Comment: Have you tried putting in breakpoints on the action in which the 500 is occurring?

Comment: Here is the error detail:
This error(HTTP 500 Internal Server Error) means that the website you are visiting had a server problem which prevented the webpage from displaying.

Comment: Put a break point in your action method and press F5 button. This will start the app in debug mode. You will be able to see the exception details.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, able to catch the error in error log,
"The underlying provider failed on Open. "
I am using window authentication in MVC+Entity Framework application.
What would be the reason?